# Loop bash script until cURL response doesn't equal string

Tags: php, bash, file-exists

I'm trying to loop a bash script (cURL below) until my remote PHP script *doesn't equal* `failure`. I've tried the following, and it works when `$fileName` exists.. but doesn't loop when it returns `failure`.

My PHP:

```
<?php
$videoFile = $_GET["name"] . ".mp4";
if (file_exists($videoFile)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
?>
```

Bash command:

```
until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "my-remote-php-script.php"); do
    printf '.'
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
while [ "$(curl -s 'http://your-url.php')" == "failure" ]; do
  echo -n '.'
  sleep 1
done
```

The `$()` places the curl in a sub-shell. The resulting string, comming from your php script, is compared with `failure`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
url="http://server.tld/foo.php"
until curl -sf "$url"; do echo -n "."; sleep 1; done
```